# C program which counts lines and operators wrong

Tags: c

This program should read rows and count operators, but counts wrong and can not find out where the errors are.

Help me find out the bugs and fix the program to be able to count rows and operators correctly.I've already tried several ways to fix it and it still counts wrong.

Current output:`Broqt na operatorite e:1 
Broqt na redovete e:1119`

Expected output: `Broqt na operatorite e:11
Broqt na redovete e:221`

```
#ifndef _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<ctype.h>

void cycleOperatorsCounter(FILE* inputStream, FILE* outputStream);
void counter(FILE* inputStream, FILE* outputStream);
int fileToFile(void);
int fileToScreen(void);
int screenToFile(void);
int screenToScreen(void);
void getFileName(char* fileName, int mode);

int menu() {
int i;


printf("----1. FILE TO FILE                  \n");
printf("----2. FILE TO SCREEN                \n");
printf("----3. KBRD TO FILE                  \n");
printf("----4. KBRD TO SCREEN                \n");
printf("----0. EXIT                          \n");
    do {
    printf("SELECT OPTION: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i", &i);
} while (i < 0 || i> 4);

return i;
}

int main(void)  {

while (1) {
    system("cls");
    switch (menu()) {
    case 1: fileToFile();
        break;
    case 2: fileToScreen();
        break;
    case 3: screenToFile();
        break;
    case 4: screenToScreen();
        break;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
    system("pause");
}
 }

 void getFileName(char* fileName, int mode) {
  while (1) {
    fflush(stdin);
    if (mode == 1) {
        printf("Input file name(.C): ");
        gets(fileName);

        if (fileName[strlen(fileName) - 2] == '.' && toupper(fileName[strlen(fileName) - 1]) == 'C') {
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Output File: ");
        gets(fileName);
        return;
    }
}
 }

int fileToFile(void) {
char inputFileName[256], outputFileName[256];
FILE *inputStream, *outputStream;

getFileName(inputFileName, 1);
if (!(inputStream = fopen(inputFileName, "r"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");
    return -1;
     }

getFileName(outputFileName, 2);
if (!(outputStream = fopen(outputFileName, "w"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\a\n");
    return -1;
 }

cycleOperatorsCounter(inputStream, outputStream);
rewind(inputStream);
counter(inputStream, outputStream);
fclose(inputStream);
fclose(outputStream);

printf("Results saved to \"%s\".\n", outputFileName);
return 0;
}

int fileToScreen(void) {
char inputFileName[256];
FILE* inputStream;

getFileName(inputFileName, 1);
if (!(inputStream = fopen(inputFileName, "r"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");
    return -1;
}

cycleOperatorsCounter(inputStream, stdout);
rewind(inputStream);
counter(inputStream, stdout);
fclose(inputStream);

return 0;
   }

int screenToFile(void) {
char outputFileName[256];
FILE *outputStream, *tempStream;
char str[999];

tempStream = fopen("temp.tmp", "w");
fflush(stdin);
printf("Napishete \"KRAI\" na nov red, kogato vuvedete teksta\n");
while (1) {
    gets(str);
    if (!strcmp(str, "KRAI")) {
        fclose(tempStream);
        tempStream = fopen("temp.tmp", "r");
        break;
    }
    fprintf(tempStream, "%s\n", str);
}

getFileName(outputFileName, 2);
if (!(outputStream = fopen(outputFileName, "w"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\a\n");
    return -1;
}

cycleOperatorsCounter(tempStream, outputStream);
rewind(tempStream);
counter(tempStream, outputStream);
fclose(tempStream);
fclose(outputStream);

printf("Results saved to \"%s\".\n", outputFileName);
return 0;
}

int screenToScreen(void) {
FILE *tempStream;
char str[999];

tempStream = fopen("temp.tmp", "w");
fflush(stdin);
printf("Napishete \"KRAI\" na nov red, kogato vuvedete teksta\n");
while (1) {
    gets(str);
    if (!strcmp(str, "KRAI")) {
        fclose(tempStream);
        tempStream = fopen("temp.tmp", "r");
        break;
    }
    fprintf(tempStream, "%s\n", str);
}

cycleOperatorsCounter(tempStream, stdout);
rewind(tempStream);
counter(tempStream, stdout);
fclose(tempStream);

return 0;
 }

 void cycleOperatorsCounter(FILE* inputStream, FILE* outputStream) {
char str[1000];
int cycleCounter = 0;
unsigned i;

while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), inputStream) != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
if ((str[i-1] == ' ' || str[i-1] == '\n' || str[i-1] == '\t' || i==0) && 
(str[i] == 'i') && (str[i + 1] == 'f') && (str[i+3] == ' ' || str[i+3] == 
'\n' || str[i+3] == '\t')) {
            cycleCounter++;
        }
        if ((str[i-1] == ' ' || str[i-1] == '\n' || str[i-1] == '\t' || 
     i==0)
            && (str[i] == 'e') && (str[i + 1] == 'l') && (str[i + 2] == 's') 
&& (str[i + 3] == 'e')
                && (str[i+5] == ' ' || str[i+6] == '\n' || str[i+7] == 
'\t')) {
            cycleCounter++;
        }
    }
}
  fprintf(outputStream, "Broqt na operatorite za cikul e: %d\n", 
 cycleCounter);

 }

void counter(FILE* inputStream, FILE* outputStream) {
char str[1000];
int Counter = 0;
unsigned i;

while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), inputStream) != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
     {
if ((str[i-1] == ' ' || str[i-1] == '\n' || str[i-1] == '\t' || i==0))
{
Counter++;
}
        }

    }
 }
fprintf(outputStream, "Broqt na redovete e: %d\n", Counter);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you also included some test data, the expected, and the current outcome. Way too much code also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `str[i+7] == '\t'` should be `str[i+6] == '\t'` But, `cycleOperatorsCounter` is a bit too complicated. It can be recoded with `strtok`. Also, `strlen` in the condition clause of a `for` loop is _slow_. Change `for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)` to `for (i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)`

Comment: @CraigEstey I did what you told me, but now I'm writing the mistake 'conflicting types for strtok.'

Comment: I ran parts of your program through Google translate to translate your `printf` [from Bulgarian?]. In your function `counter`, by "rows" do you mean words? What is the exact definition of what you're trying to count. If you're reading source code as your other function implies (e.g. it counts `if/else`), how do you want to parse `if (foo == 1)` [which counts as 4] and `if (foo==1)` [which counts as 2].

Comment: No, by my function counter, I mean rows, not words. @CraigEstey

Comment: Ah, I see. I would say lines. Okay, I can see why `counter` has a much too high value. You just need to count newlines

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  in the C standard, this results in undefined behavior.  Unfortunately, visual studio does not follow the c standard.  If you want to flush `stdin` suggest you use: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}`

Comment: regarding: `gets(fileName);`  the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and completely removed from the latest versions of the C standard due to its' many problems.  Suggest using: `fgets()` (read the MAN page for `fgets()` )

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");`  this does not tell the user the cause of the problem.  when an error indication is from a C library function, call: `perror()` something like: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  This will output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`. Usually this would be immediately followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
     {
if ((str[i-1] == ' ' || str[i-1] == '\n' || str[i-1] == '\t' || i==0))`  this, on the first iteration, results in accessing memory before the beginning of the buffer: `str[]`  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Similar considerations exist for: `    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
if ((str[i-1] == ' ' || str[i-1] == '\n' || str[i-1] == '\t' || i==0) && 
(str[i] == 'i') && (str[i + 1] == 'f') && (str[i+3] == ' ' || str[i+3] == 
'\n' || str[i+3] == '\t'))` and probably other places in the posted code

Comment: regarding: `system( "cls" );` and `system( "pause");`  Not all OSs have such shell commands. so the posted code is not portable.  You could try using: `putc( 0xff );` instead of the call to 'cls'.  For 'pause' you could use the (see prior comment) to flush `stdin`, then call `getchar()` one more time

Comment: OT:  regarding: `#ifndef _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif`  the first line in a program will NEVER have the name: `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` already defined so this can be reduced to only: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Answer (score 0):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

That is, finding the `if` and the `else` is more easily done with `strtok` and `strcmp`.

And, to count rows/lines, simply doing `fgets` and counting or doing `fgetc` and counting the `\n` will work.

Hopefully, this will get you farther:

```
void
cycleOperatorsCounter(FILE *inputStream, FILE *outputStream)
{
    char *bp;
    char *tok;
    char str[1000];
    int cycleCounter = 0;

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), inputStream) != NULL) {
        bp = str;
        while (1) {
            tok = strtok(bp," \t\n");
            if (tok == NULL)
                break;
            bp = NULL;

            if (strcmp(tok,"if") == 0) {
                cycleCounter++;
                continue;
            }

            if (strcmp(tok,"else") == 0) {
                cycleCounter++;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    fprintf(outputStream, "Broqt na operatorite za cikul e: %d\n",
        cycleCounter);

}

void
counter(FILE *inputStream, FILE *outputStream)
{
    int Counter = 0;

    // count number of lines
    // NOTE: either of these should work:

#if 1
    char str[1000];
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), inputStream) != NULL)
        ++Counter;
#else
    while (1) {
        int chr = fgetc(inputStream);
        if (chr == EOF)
            break;
        if (chr == '\n')
            ++Counter;
    }
#endif

    fprintf(outputStream, "Broqt na redovete e: %d\n", Counter);
}
```